# The [heisenbug] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I just found the [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) tag.  It has 3 followers and 112 questions.  Its tag wiki excerpt is:

> A software bug that disappears or alters its behavior when one attempts to probe, study, or isolate it.

This a meta-tag, and questions about heisenbugs are almost always off-topic because if you can create an MCVE about a heisenbug then, [as πάντα ῥεῖ explained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328275/3476191), it's not a heisenbug anymore.

Shall we burninate it?

Comment: Absolutely supported. If I look at [Jeff' Atwood's](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) point, made time ago, this certainly doesn't add any value to a quesiton.

Comment: I think this is a silly but useful tag, because it indicates a problem that doesn't always happen (or is hard to reproduce).

Comment: @ssube But questions about heisenbugs are nearly always going to be off-topic as πάντα ῥεῖ and I explained, and [heisenbug] is a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: @ssube: What does the tag add for such questions? You can still add a sentence that it does not occur every time.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +65/-13. A1 (Saying Yes) +42/-4. A2 (Saying No) +1/0

Comment: I don’t agree that such questions are off-topic, as the possibility to reproduce the problem is not a strict requirement. Questioner should attempt to create an MCVE as hard as possible, still, if they can’t, the question might still be answerable by looking at the source code and problem description. Sometimes, even at the first sight. However, that doesn’t make the tag a useful question category. `[heisenbug]` is as useful as `[annoying]` or `[tricky]`…

Comment: I wonder how many questions tagged thus are accurately tagged. Given the numerous low effort debugging questions, I suspect only a few.

Comment: Removing this tag will invalidate nearly every non trivial memory fault you'll ever seen under windows. It's not a good idea.

Comment: @Owl Removing this tag does not change the rules regarding what is on topic and therefore won’t “invalidate” any questions. I’m proposing we burninate this tag because the fact that a problem is a heisenbug belongs in the question body; this tag does not make the question easier for experts to find.

Comment: I just **love it.** Douglas Adams would love this definition too (or was *he* Stackoverflow user who created this tag long time ago?)
 
"There is a theory which states that if ever anyone discovers exactly what the Universe is for and why it is here, it will instantly disappear and be replaced by something even more bizarre and inexplicable. 
There is another theory which states that this has already happened."

Please keep it, SO needs some humour. :-D

Comment: A Heisenbug can be 100% reproducible. E.g. the code fails every time when run with debugging switched off, and works every time when run with debugging switched on.

Comment: Your premise is wrong. Creating/presenting an  MCVE is NOT a requirement on SO !

Comment: @TaW It is for debugging questions; [there's a close reason for it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: Quick follow ups. 1. The comments on this post have been cleaned to facilitate discussion about the burnination of this tag. Feel free to hold off on the puns and other off-topic discussions until the end of the burnination process. 2. Given that there has been some discussion to save the tag, I'm leaving this open for another day of discussion.

Comment: What's with the need to remove any sense of humour or community from the site?  It's a tiny tag, just leave it, and some people will get curious when they see and maybe chuckle.

Comment: @Holger I agree 100%. And I wish that there were actually some people willing to help with questions that go beyond "Find an error in 10 lines of code".

Comment: @Jonathan. I don't see any humor or community building value in the existence of this tag, and thus we're not losing any of that by burninating it. That aside, jokes and humor are noise, and SO is *built* on minimizing noise. If you want humor, you can always go read comics or visit /r/funny.

Comment: Tags are used to find questions. If I were feeling funny, I'd went to help several people with their heisenbugs, just for the sake of complexity of such endeavour. My vote is to keep it.

Comment: @TylerH, It's like there used to be a bunch of interesting questions but then they got closed as subjective, or historical, etc. That sort of thing brings people into the site, and then they answer questions while here. Its like a supermarket selling certain items at cost/for a loss to bring people in the door. People don't want to visit a dry boring site. Especially not people who are writing the answers. (people writing questions already have motivation to come here)

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q +166/-29. A1 (Saying Yes) +119/-10. A2 (Saying No) +22/-29. A3 (Saying Yes) +5/-1. A4 (Saying Yes) +12/-1. A5 (Saying No) +5/-3. The community has voted in favor of burninating the tag.

Comment: @BhargavRao All the questions in the tag have been closed. Isn't that stage 3 or something?

Comment: We don't want humor like the heisenbug tag, because humor is noise, but we're quite happy with humor like using the word burninate and imagry like Trogdor.  Seems there's a bit of a double standard here.

Comment: @Phil Yes, there is a different standard here: Meta is much more relaxed and typically has much more room for humor than the main site.

Comment: Never used the tag, but am sad it’s gone. “Heisenbug” is such a great word, and it succinctly conveys an important property of the bug, i.e. that it doesn’t happen when debugging is on. Minor but significant loss for SO, IMO.

Comment: @mRotten It may be a great word, but that doesn’t make it a great tag. Tags are to categorize questions for searchability; whether a problem is a Heisenbug belongs in the question body, not the tags.

Comment: @NobodyNada I disagree, but I don’t feel strongly about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Progress:

The [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=heisenbug),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheisenbug%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheisenbug%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheisenbug%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bheisenbug%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197808)

[Dashboard for progress](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=328270)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) tag — just flag/vote to close the question.

#### Do not downvote questions in order to trigger roomba

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 112):

> ... because it is, by definition, not possible to create an MCVE about a heisenbug.

That's not actually true.
The most common problems with [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug)s are

- Undefined behavior of code called in large code bases, causing memory corruption elsewhere
- Use of uninitialized variables (which is merely UB of course)
- Untreated race conditions, that change behavior if you try to observe them
- ... I'm sure there are more

If you sorted out what the reason was, it would be easy to reproduce it with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but then the question is already solved.

May be for self answered questions, this tag could add some value (for future research), but certainly not in general.

---

As Jeff Atwood pointed out in his [coding horror blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/new-programming-jargon/) that time, a **Heisenbug** is simply *unknown*:

> ## 8. Heisenbug
>
> unknown
>   [image]
>   A computer bug that disappears or alters its characteristics when an attempt is made to study it. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug#Heisenbug))

---

So yes, I support burninating this tag.

Comment: One note about UB: It can look like defined behavior, so just finding an MCVE may not clear up the issue. For example, I used to think that `int x;` set `x` to `0`, when it really leaves it uninitialized -- if I had code that depended on it being `0`, my MCVE would be something like `int x; std::cout << x << std::endl; // why does this write 59129075`, and that problem wouldn't be already solved.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes but at least it makes it obvious that your assumption was wrong, specially if a duck is there to help ;).

Comment: @Braiam Oh, for sure. My point is that some UB isn't obvious UB, and _that_ could be a good question. Well, probably a dupe at this point, but still.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes _"that some UB isn't obvious UB"_ That's what I've trying to address with _"large code bases"_.

Comment: No, I was picking at "*If you sorted out what the reason was, it would be easy to reproduce it with a MCVE, but then the question is already solved.*". Not all problems are solvable with an MCVE.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes [MCVE] is primarily meant to _reproduce_ particular problems, not to solve them.

Comment: @NobodyNada May be we misunderstood, that's what we're both actually telling here.I just tried to give a bit more detail and background. I'm not counter voting your request here.

Comment: Super late to the party, but the word "unknown" in Jeff's blog means that the origin of the term is unknown. It doesn't describe the term.

Comment: The primary problem with this answer is by the time the OP knows to add the tag he has a clue what's going on.

Comment: Another Heisenbug category:  That which only breaks in release builds, but is fine in debug build: `#ifdef _DEBUG` code that should be in all builds for example.

Answer (score 12):

Upon reading the definition, I have apparently encountered quite a few heisenbugs in the realm of Java Time-Date issues and a whole slew of questions related to leap years, ancient time, and legacy timezones.

**However, labeling them heisenbugs would not have helped improve these questions nor increase its solvability.**

Conceptually, heisenbugs exist, but understanding that they're called heisenbugs (which I didn't even know about until today) or caring that they are heisenbugs, doesn't help solvers in any way. We know what the problem is (inconsistent time values, in this case). We don't need it to be classified as such when the question describes the anomalous behavior already.

Examples of Java time-based questions I have encountered that I would retroactively describe as heisenbugs:

[Java Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR sometimes off by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26513482/java-calendar-day-of-year-sometimes-off-by-one/)

[Discrepancy when converting ancient dates between java.util.Date and java.time.Instant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393619/discrepancy-when-converting-ancient-dates-between-java-util-date-and-java-time-i/)

[java calendar returns wrong week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25917641/java-calendar-returns-wrong-week/)

All of these questions had sample code that had valid MCVEs that revealed heisenbug-like problems when the provided parameters or MCVE were adjusted.

Answer (score 6):

I think we should examine two things here: wether the tag serves a purpose and wether it is more important to enforce a rule than to have the benefit of that purpose.

The tag serves a purpose, two actually: People interested in Heisenbugs can find them by the tag, and OP can actually make a bit more clear that (s)he thinks it is a Heisenbug.

Now, let‘s have a look at the underlying question wether it is more important to enforce a rule than to have the benefit of those purposes. My 2 cents: We are talking of rules, not laws. At the end of the day, SO is about helping each other out and not about enforcing rules. And help is especially needed if you track a problem down and it eludes one by using basic and well known techniques.

I understand that keeping the tag creates a precedence (law jargon, again), but does it hurt to keep it? I rather keep it than to see SO (and by extension SE) becoming a kafkaesque bureaucracy in which the rules are more important than the purpose.

As per the fear of a precedence: One can always argue with this very discussion. If the consent is that the tag is worth to keep it, it is the consent of the people who actually fill this site with content: the community.

Comment: I disagree that the tag serves a useful purpose. 1) "People interested in Heisenbugs can find them by the tag" But the tag is too general to be useful. Just the fact that a problem is a Heisenbug is only a superficial detail that doesn't really tell you anything about the root cause of the issue. We don't have experts in solving Heisenbugs, we have experts in the underlying frameworks and technologies -- knowing that a question is about a Heisenbug doesn't make it easier for experts or future Googlers to find.

Comment: 2) "OP can actually make a bit more clear that (s)he thinks it is a Heisenbug." That's a detail which goes in the question body, not in the tags.

Comment: It's like (from what I hear of it now) [tag:homework].

Comment: @NobodyNada Not to disgress, but I doubt it is on others to decide on what people are interested in and how they approach information. The usefulness of a thing derives from wether it has a benefit. The fact alone that we are discussing about it seems to point out that there are in fact people (their number is irrelevant) think they benefit from the tags existence. Call me an inclusionist. ;)

Comment: @NobodyNada To make it a bit more clear: You can not find a heisenbug easily if it goes into the description only.

Answer (score 4):

I could imagine a piece of code which shows the bug as an MCVE and which also shows that using some specific debugging techniques (e. g. inserting a `print` on a specific line) make the weird behavior disappear.

That would be a Heisenbug with a specific MCVE.

But I agree that it doesn't add value to SO (unless for researchers on the topic of Heisenbugs), so I can easily live with burninating it.

Answer (score -7):

I am a physicist. I can understand that people who don't know anything (or enought) about quantum mechanics don't appreciate the brilliant metaphore behind this "word composition".

I have to agree that not everybody should understand quantum mechanics who just wants to solve a little coding problem here or there. As much as I love this word "heisenbug", there needs to be a common denominator, such as "REST", something that "everybody speaks".

I am a bit sad, however, about 1984 type of things, we will end up with double plus plus if we go on like this.

So this is a bit of an ambivalent topic but if the goal is to not educate (or motivate to learn or make curious about important "things") the new generation beyond telling them on how to fix bugs, then the tag needs to be "deleted", however this will further separate the gap between people who know what it means and people who don't. It is a bit of a sad thing, in the eyes of a physicist, that even super basic quantum mechanics is not really understood by a person who can write three lines of python code. The hardware that executes those three lines would not exist without Heisenberg.

Bottom line, sad to see the tag go, but if this is a website strictly about coding, then indeed, `heisenbug` is a confusing metaphor.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your point. We aren't getting rid of this tag because it's confusing, but because it isn't a helpful way to categorize questions.

Comment: _because it isn't a helpful way to categorize questions_ Tags are not just for categorizing but also for describing. It is a pity to see it go. Rules for (perceived) rules sake

Answer (score -8):

Yes you can make a MCVE for a Heisenberg now despite the fact this was historically impossible. Address-space-layout-randomization makes this possible. Would you like an example. If you care enough I'll be happy to produce a canonical demonstration.

More directly, the very first [heisenbug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/heisenbug) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55179569/how-to-debug-code-which-only-works-with-breakpoints-set) I found to be very much on topic from the question alone, but was disappointed with the only answer (it's a delay self-answer so we *know* it's right for him).

I found this tag to be kind of useful. When you see questions tagged with it you know they're going to be nasty thorny memory trashing issues, and you very quickly have an idea of what you're looking for in the code in the question.

Comment: You undermine your own premise by linking to a question where the problem turned out to be a race condition, not a memory issue -- there's no reason to assume ASLR would make any difference. Furthermore, that question perfectly illustrates the inherent problem of actually finding and fixing a heisenbug: once you've done so to the point where you could make the question answerable by others, you've already completed a successful debugging session and the question itself adds no value (beyond perhaps serving as a debugging tutorial, but that's definitely off topic for SO).

Comment: Sure it was a race condition in this case. But deleting this question/answer after years was totally unnecessary. Sometimes this sort of posts is what you find late at night on Google and they make you not giving up the hope: I'm not alone, the problem has been solved by someone ...

Comment: WOAH WHOA, who's talking about deleting questions? We're talking about burning a tag, with Trogdor assistance.

Comment: @Braiam The question linked by Joshua was deleted after he posted about it. Guess its part of the "meta effect"